# Node.js nano library for couchdb: timeout needed

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I've been working with the nano library, and found myself with a need for having timeouts for my couchdb requests.

I'm using db.search/db.get/db.destroy/db.insert and as far as I could tell from the documentation there's no easy way to add a timeout.

These are async functions that pass a callback as a parameter. Ideally I would prefer not to modify the callbacks, but i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `nano` you can provide a object that is passed to the request object:

```
var db = require('nano')({"requestDefaults" : { "proxy" : "http://someproxy" }});
```

For example, that sets a proxy to `http://someproxy`.

To change the timeout, you can use the [`timeout` property](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

This code should work:

```
var db = require('nano')({
  "uri": "http://localhost:5984/mydb",
  "requestDefaults" : { "timeout" : "100" } // in miliseconds
});
```

The default timeout in linux is about `20000`ms, 20 seconds.